# window.location.href not working in form onsubmit

Tags: javascript

So i have a form, and `onsubmit="return reg_check(this)"` where `reg_check()` is a javascript function in the header which is supposed to check the form data, and since one of its tasks is to check if the username is in the database which requires php, i want to redirect to a php page that does this task.

Problem is: `window.location.href` is not working! Here's the function (reduced version) and of course the `main.php` is just a random page i got:

```
function reg_check(myForm) {
    alert("before redirect..");
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/main.php?width=" + screen.width + "&height=" + screen.height;
    alert("after redirect..");
}
```

The `before redirect` and `after redirect` alerts work, it just doesn't redirect? It remains in the same page.

Also, if I tried to redirect from the body by just typing :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("before redirect..");
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/main.php?width=" + screen.width + "&height=" + screen.height;
    alert("after redirect..");
</script>
```

it redirects.

Any ideas of how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to `return false;` from your `reg_check` function and then in your onsubmit, change it to:

```
onsubmit="return reg_check(this);"
```

This will cancel the form submission. And if you want to let the form submit as normal, just return true from `reg_check`.

Edit (to be more clear you need to add return false; from your function):

```
function reg_check(myForm) {
    alert("before redirect..");
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/main.php?width=" + screen.width + "&height=" + screen.height;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Nara sorry didn't say that correctly, I've updated the answer and you should be good now.

Comment: Huh? Then what is your question? This resolves the issue that I thought you were asking. What is different in my answer is that you need to return false; from your function. I'll update the answer to be more clear.

Comment: this is my test.php        <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function reg_check(myForm) {
alert("before redirect..");
window.location.href = "http://localhost/re.php"
alert("after redirect..");
return false;
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return reg_check(this)" >
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Register!" tabindex="13" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html> where re.php is <?php
echo("it works!");
?>

Comment: The solution I provided you with will resolve the issue of not being able to redirect during a form submit. What you have just pasted in has some additional problems...the href property must be the full path with the http://. I suggest that you take a step back and update your code one step at a time. I promise you this will work.

Comment: In your updated comment, you must also remove the alert("after redirect.."); from the function as this could not logically happen after a redirect. Then you should be good to go.

Comment: oh i did provide the http:// in my code it's just that this website omitted it thinking i was sending u a url i guess. and yeah the 2nd alert is useless. but the problem is still as it is :/ if i call my function from the body, as in <script type="text/javascript">
reg_check(); </script> after omitting the (myForm) in the function name, it works just fine?

Comment: I've nothing more for you...if you want to redirect during an onsubmit, you need to cancel the form submission by returning false.

Comment: Actually one more comment, you should use window.location instead of window.location.href as well as you can run into problems with some browsers. IE6 I believe is one.

Comment: @Craig - you are a frickin' genius...can't believe I've spent the last hour messing with this and all I needed was a "return" and a "return false".  Thanks!

Comment: @Craig So what if I want both submit correctly and reload the page after submit?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen problems in IE where I've had to do the following:

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

Specifically within a jQuery AJAX success handler.  Can't really speculate to why other than for me, it worked.

Actually I did

```
window.location.replace(url)
```

Which replaces the current page in the history.  Nice trick that!

Comment: On some browsers, if the (url) is the same as the current address bar url, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but found the answer here [Javascript: window.location.href doesn't redirect when calling function within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369635/javascript-window-location-href-doesnt-redirect-when-calling-function-within-a) . 
My button was reloading the page by default so if you add an

```
 event.PreventDefault();
```

To your function it should work.

Answer (score -1):

[RESOLVED] I had a similar problem in redirecting to some other url from client script. Implemented window.open function instead and it worked. You may have for instance, a function say ChangeCity() for your html control event that gets called with onchange event.

```
function ChangeCity() {
    switch ($("#currentCity").val()) {
        case "NY":
              var url = '@Url.Action("New York City", "Home", new { @area = "" },Request.Url.Scheme)';
            window.location.href = url;
            window.open(url,"_top");
            return false;
```

/*  cases for other cities */

```
    }
```

You may like to explore details on [window.location.href redirection -Alternative Solution](http://axarrow.com/QuestionForum/Question/53/Javascript-window-location-window-location-href-not-working-(Resolved)-for-redirecting-url-from-client)