# window.location.href only works when cashe is cleared in ie

Tags: javascript, html

Bit of a strange one here. I have a bit of javascript that does some validation on a form, if the validation is passed I use window.location.href to send teh user to a new page.

This works great in all browsers except internet explorer. The strange thing is that in IE it will not work. Clear the cashe, even if the user has never been to this site and try again and it will work great!

Any ideas? I have tested this on 10+ computers and found this to be the correct cause and cure!

Comment: I think what you want to do is cancel the form submission. Can you gives us a code example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109527/window-location-href-not-working This post might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
location.reload(true);
```

at the top of that page..

you can try to redirect using `self.location="yourPage.html";` or `top.location="yourPage.html";`.

But what will happen to users who have got Javascript disabled in your browsers..??

imho, you should validate through a server-side script and redirect using it only..

Comment: Thanks for the advice - seems to give a good solution in all browsers now. Sorry for replying late.