# window.location.href not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, window.location

I have a Meteor application that gives recommendations in the path /myrecommendations and where I am checking if a person is logged in, and if not, the user is alerted that recommendations cannot be given unless logged in, and is redirected to the main directory ("/"):

```
    alert("You must be logged in to get recommendations");
    window.location.href("/");
    event.PreventDefault();
```

The problem is that nothing happens; the browser remains in the /myrecommendations. I have looked at similar questions, like [window.location.href not working in form onsubmit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109527/window-location-href-not-working),
window.location.reload(true); and a host of other similar ones, but either their suggested remedy do not work (like both the ones above) or they address a slightly different issue.

Answer (score 3):

`window.location.href` is not a function. If you want to send a user back to the root path, try this:

```
window.location.pathname = '/';
```

However, I do recommend using a router in Meteor, where you can ensure a user is logged in and set the redirect should they not be logged in. [Iron Router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) is a popular example.

Answer (score 2):

try this way:

```
window.location.href = "url you want";
```