# Not able to redirect users using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where user will click on it to send invites to his friend on gmail

here is the button

```
<button onclick="TwkInvite()" class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>Import your Gmail Contacts
</button>
```

here is the javascript part

```
function TwkInvite() {
    alert('function is called');
    window.location.href = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=*********-*************.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/app/invite-send&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code";
}
```

I have tried window.location.href, window.location, location.href everything

This function is being executed perfectly as alert is also executed but i don't know why it doesn't redirect to google website, whenever i click on button the page get refreshed

No error is printed, i checked mozilla console also but no error found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.location.href not working :(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109527/window-location-href-not-working)

Comment: `<button onclick="TwkInvite();return false;" class="btn">` use this. This will prevent parent form getting submitted, if there is any.

Comment: can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109527/window-location-href-not-working i hope it will help. It suggest to return false or use event.preventDefault() after location.href.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan write it as an answer so i can up vote & mark it as answer

Comment: how do you include the javascript part in your page ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis my problem has been solved by adding TwkInvite();return false; as the button was in the form

Comment: ok in that case great

Comment: BDW @jeremy-denis Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question says that there is no error in the console, that means what ever is causing redirect is a default action. It could be submitting a form for all we know. This will prevent parent form getting submitted, if there is any.

You can use `return false` to prevent that from happening.

```
<button onclick="TwkInvite();return false;" class="btn">
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not preventing the button to reload the page, which it does in Chrome at least. To prevent this, you have to prevent the default event from firing.

Define your button like this, so you forward the event parameter to you handler:

```
<button onclick="TwkInvite(event)" class="btn">
```

Now prevent the default event handling with `event.preventDefault()`

```
function TwkInvite(e) {
    alert('function is called');
    window.location.href = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=*********-*************.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/app/invite-send&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code";

    // The event is in window.event in IE
    var e =  e || window.event; 

    // e.prevenDefault() for modern browsers, e.returnValue for IE
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a permissions issue.

When I turned this into a snippet, I got this error in the console:

```
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=*********-*************…/app/invite-send&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

```js
function TwkInvite() {    
    window.location.href = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=*********-*************.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/app/invite-send&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="TwkInvite()" class="btn">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>Import your Gmail Contacts
</button>
```