# jQuery redirect to another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am trying to direct to another file after successful login. However, it doesn't seem that I was able to go to b.html after login successfully alert is displayed. It seems to be remain in the same page. I have tried `document.location.href`,  `window.location.replace` but it doesn't seem to work

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
    }

    function init() {
        document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click", saveData, false);
        document.getElementById("btnGet").addEventListener("click", getData, false);
    }

    function getData() {
        var email1 = document.getElementById("email1").value;
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
        var email2 = window.localStorage.getItem("email");
        var pass2 = window.localStorage.getItem("pass");
        if (email1 == email2 && pass1 == pass2) {
            alert("Login successfully");
            window.location.href = "/b.html";
        } else {
            alert("Invalid login credentials");
        }
    }
</script>
<form class="login-form">
    <input type="email" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
    <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="Password" required/>
    <button id="btnGet" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: use complete URL with domain and check. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109527/window-location-href-not-working-in-form-onsubmit

Comment: 1. don't call anything `name="submit"` in a form. 2. If you submit the form, you leave the page and the script may not get the time to execute or the form will not send anything to the server. Instead have the form action redirect. 3. use a fully qualified URL in location.href - PS: Change the button to type="button" if you need to do JavaScript in the handler - otherise do stuff on the server or cancel the submit

Comment: but if i have a form action redirect, wouldnt it still direct user to that page even though its fail login?

Comment: Where did you save the credentials in the localstorage? And according to the script, if you have successfully stored anything in localstorage and it is the same as what you fill in, you are redirected. Anyone can just go straight to b.html anyway

Comment: yup thats what i thought, i have successfully output successful login, but it doesnt seem to be going to that b.html

Comment: if thats the case, then add `onsubmit="return false"`

Comment: It would be better to dispatch the action after submitting the form instead of clicking the login button. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why your redirection doesn't work is that clicking the `Login` button submits the form. This is a normal behaviour of the web browser. In your case you need to this prevent this default behaviour.

Using `jQuery`, you can do it like this:

```
$('form.login-form').submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Since you're not using `jQuery` in your code at all, you might be interested in such a version:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

An alternative solution would be not to add `type="submit"` attribute to the login button.

But the best you can do (and what internet users are used to) is to redirect the user after submitting the form. Then this will work not only when a user clicks the button but when he presses `ENTER` as well etc.

Then your code should look like this:

```
(() => {
    let form;

    function init() {
        form = document.querySelector('login-form');

        if (!form) {
            throw new ElementNotFoundException();
        }

        form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmitHandler);
    }

    function onSubmitHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // get values, validate...

        window.location.href = 'b.html';
    }

    init();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe location href is not correctly writen, please replace `window.location.href = "/b.html";` to `window.location.href = "b.html";`

Comment: Are you sure that b.html in the same directory where your html is?

Comment: yes it is, i have tried header() and it works, doesnt work with this jquery though